# Can I ask a question about a wordpress plugin?

Tags: discussion, support

The plugin has zero documentation. I need to figure out how it stores information so I can program a way to extract data from it that it's storing. It doesn't even have a page just a github which it doesn't appear the author visits much or supports.

The plugin stores comment votes but I don't know where it's storing the info. Once I can figure out where it is storing the votes I can move forward to formulate a way to extract and use this data. I opened up all the files and tried reverse engineering it but I need help because I can't figure out how it works.

Comment: It would actually help if you would link to that repository on GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/MMAlexandru/rating-system    I want to be able to use the total upvotes and downvotes per user

Comment: Why am I not getting any points for these upvotes?

Comment: @user6686780 Reputation on meta is synced with the main site - you don't get individual reputation for Q&A on meta.

Comment: So it's just there for show, no points at all given for upvotes on meta on any site? (no points given on main site either)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are struggling with plugin code and it is open source, you can ask questions about parts of the code, pasting code parts in the questions and describing in what and why you are struggling with that piece of code.

You could also link the complete repository for more context.

Those kind of questions are fine.

Just avoid to paste walls of code and just say *"please help me with this"*, but instead show research effort and ask specific questions.